# Getting error W3 Total Cache (Version 0.9.2.4)

Tags: php, wordpress

Getting error after installing **W3 Total Cache (Version 0.9.2.4)** , as

> Blockquote W3 Total Cache Error: Default settings are in use. The configuration file could not be read or doesn't exist. Please **save the settings** to create the file.

save the settings is appearing as button , but even after clicking on it nothing changes.Nothing happens.
It's not even working. No css, js is minifing.

Can some one please tell what is wrong with plugin?

Comment: Since it requires special permissions to perform its magic, it probably can't write some file. If you can't chmod 777 `wp-content/` and `wp-content/uploads/` (temporarily), then I'm not really sure how you can create those files manually. Try poking around the FAQ and the associated forums. I'm sure you're not the only one having this issue.

Comment: Yes , its having permission.Apparently I come to know about problem that my setup is on 5 servers , so its not able to edit config for wp cache.Now I need to edit its config and synch it on all 5 servers.

Comment: Nasty. I hope you manage to solve it...

Comment: I have local setup.Done every single change on local.Committed in svn , uploaded on servers and synced to all web nodes..Doing it all day long...Dont know why we have many web nodes and single db.!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apparently I come to know about problem that my setup is on 5 servers , so its not able to edit config for wp cache.Now I need to edit its config and synch it on all 5 servers

Answer (score 2):

I got same error "*W3 Total Cache Error: Default settings are in use. The configuration file could not be read or doesn't exist. Please save the settings to create the file* " on my production server once I migrated from an existing server to new server.

I noticed following two files **master.php** and **master-admin.php** were missing from location **wp-content/w3tc-config**

Once I moved these files to the new server the error message was gone.

You may also need to run following commands

```
cp /wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/wp-content/advanced-cache.php /wp-content/advanced-cache.php
mkdir /wp-content/cache
chmod 777 /wp-content/cache
mkdir /wp-content/w3tc-config
chmod 777 /wp-content/w3tc-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the plugin? Or disabling it?

Comment: Apparently I come to know about problem that my setup is on 5 servers , so its not able to edit config for wp cache.Now I need to edit its config and synch it on all 5 servers.